# Jetty IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty

I had an app that was running fine with app engine 1.7.1, but when I upgraded to 1.7.5 all my library dependencies were broken.

So I think I got all the dependencies corrected, so at least I don't have any compile time errors, but when I try and run it I get the following error:

```
Mar 15, 2013 11:09:34 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed Jersey Web Application: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Mar 15, 2013 11:09:34 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@c65fb1{/,/Users/bbarrand12/Documents/Eclipse/Workspace/MovieFoneToGo/war}: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Mar 15, 2013 11:09:34 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@5dfa490: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Mar 15, 2013 11:09:34 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:228)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$Servers.startup(DevAppServerImpl.java:451)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:198)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
```

Any ideas why this is broken. Perhaps I just to update some of my other jars?

Here are my dependencies:
[image]

Comment: Can these posts help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12241279/2086065 http://stackoverflow.com/a/13103587/2086065 http://stackoverflow.com/a/13552626/2086065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there could be a compatibility problem between Jersey and GAE. According to [**this**](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava), Jersey versions that are now compatible with Google App Engine are 1.5 and 1.1.5.

This [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166382/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-deploying-to-app-engi) may also help.